# RegEx grabbing information based on string results

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I am trying to get a users name from a list of data.  The data is held in a weird format where 3 character integers are formed to resemble the next field.  In the Data below:

Data

```
129ABCDIEN ABCDHERS ABCDIT UABCU000 212 113P.O. BOX  106000 212 1182920 
LAKEABCD AVE.000 212 126ST. JOSEPH,  MI 41234-0132000 217 114(123) 983- 
12340000123 207 109PAGE    10000265 134From:    7/01/00     To:   
7/31/000000293 110Account #:123 1041106000 265 121Tax ID #: 123-12-1234000 
212 118SARITEIO SARICO JR000 212
```

I would like to select

```
SARITEIO SARICO JR
```

The constant in the data is TAX ID#: [21 character] followed by '000 212 ' and the number of characters of the name.  In this case being 18 characters.

```
,---- Normal String
|.,---- number of characters
|||                  |- End of the string
118SARITEIO SARICO JR000
```

Currently I have the select for the number of characters, but i'm not sure how to reuse the select to select the next variable

Current RegEx:

```
/Tax ID #: .{20}(..)
```

I am new to RegEx so any point in the right direction would be helpful.

I also have the ability to use any functionality in C#.

Comment: Try [`Tax ID.{18}(?:\s*\d+)*((?i)[a-z]+(?:\s*[a-z]+)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/1jk4tw/1) and access to first capturing group

Comment: @revo Awesome, that worked.  Could you answer below and explain how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your rules there would be a straightforward regex to match desired pattern in subject string:

```
Tax ID.{18}\s*\d{3}(?:\s*\d+)*((?i)[a-z]+(?:\s[a-z]+)*)
```

Matching sensitive `Tax ID` is followed by matching 18 number of characters (except a newline since I wasn't sure if your data contains newlines or not). It matches optional whitespaces (including newlines) afterwards and exact `3` digits followed by an optional similar pattern. Next would be matching a sequence of words containing English alphabets only. This one is captured and has case-insensitivity flag `(?i)` set.

You only have to obtain access to first capturing group.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJY9OR/1)